# Display NSMUtableArray items in Iphone?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

I am a newbie to objective-C and I have a particular concept but couldn't get where to start and how to start.I need the advice of experts over here..
My concept is:
I have to load the xml response from a service url and store it in NSMutableArray.And then I have to display that particular Array data in rows and columns..something like adding in gridview and when a user select a particular item that value should display in textfield giving user an option to select only one value at a time.suppose the data I receive from url is id's(suppose 16 values(which may vary) from a particular tag in xml response)then when I have to bind this to gridview and give an option to select one value and display in textfield..I donno where to start and how to start?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by customing UITableView and made it to load array data in rows and columns correspondingly..